# Connection Error when starting selendroid server

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selendroid

I am trying to run android hybrid app tests with `selendroid` standalone server. When I start the server it successfully starts but I get the following error for the emulators. -

```
WARNING: Could not get avdName for device emulator-5672 
io.selendroid.standalone.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException:
Cannot establish a connection to device.
at io.selendroid.standalone.android.TelnetClient.<init>(TelnetClient.java:40)
```

Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Selendroid before, but it seems to be that your emulator is not properly recognized or you given it a bad name. According to:
http://selendroid.io/setup.html

Please follows your steps:

> You can check that the application(s) and the devices are recognized by opening a browser and navigating to: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status.

Check if emulator-5672  has specific name and use it on run.

Also read patiently above tutorial and check on its GitHub page if there isn't any simillar issue to this.

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for the links. I made some changes in the emulator - ram size as per http://selendroid.io/setup.html. But I still get the error. However, inspite of the error I am able to run the emulator successfully now